# Can I keep my PhD thesis chapter intro as is when publishing it as an article if another article was published in the meantime that paraphrases it?

Tags: publications, thesis, plagiarism, self-plagiarism

I graduated from my PhD in 2019 and published my thesis online. Just before COVID I submitted an article based on a thesis chapter, but because of life getting in the way I was unable to finish it and it was taken out of the review process with encouragements to submit it again.

I am almost done with the new version, but I discovered that an article about the same topic has been published last year by another team to another journal, with an introduction that paraphrases my own introduction to a large extent. The rest of the paper is actually interesting, and they do cite my thesis.

The question is, can I still submit my own article whose introduction is very close to my thesis chapter? Or should I rewrite the intro from a completely new angle because otherwise this would count as plagiarizing the paper that was published by the other group?

Comment: Can you clarify: the paraphrasing article was written by you in a fit of absence of mind or by someone else using your thesis?

Comment: Are you suspecting that one of the reviewers kept a copy of your manuscript and just paraphrased what you said? Or are you saying that the newly published paper pretty much addresses the same issues as you had done in your intro, without ever seeing your intro? In other words, are we talking about plagiarism or about independent production of similar text?

Comment: The article with the paraphrasing introduction was written by another research group. In their intro they do cite results from my thesis (which is already available online) but the structure and flow of ideas is similar to the chapter I want to publish. The rest of their article is novel and interesting.

Comment: Then 'paraphrasing' is not the word. You should edit your question.

Comment: What do you mean by "can" here? Are you, as the tags indicate, worried about plagiarism? Clearly if text A was written (and even published in the form of a thesis) before text B, then text A cannot possibly plagiarize text B.

Comment: @cheery.beach7701 I'm not sure I understand, could you please clarify?

Comment: @adam-přenosil I agree. What I want is to publish a text (say C) based on A after B was published by someone else. Does that make more sense?

Comment: "Paraphrasing" means taking something already written/said and modifying it. What you are saying, if I understand it well, is that they said what you were going to say before you said it. That's not paraphrasing.

Comment: @cheery.beach7701 thanks for clarifying. They did paraphrase my introduction as you defined it, but the rest of the article was novel

Comment: I don't know if your question can be answered without reading the exact text, eg how much of it is common knowledge, etc. My gut feeling is that there's no problem with what you are proposing. Still seems like a judgement call.

Comment: I see, thank you for the feedback so far. I will discuss this with my co-authors. If someone wants to add to the conversation please feel free to do so. I will leave this question open for some time just in case

Comment: Were you cited in that other paper?

Comment: @user195539 I understand that. What I am saying is that publishing your thesis chapter as (part of) a paper cannot possibly be considered plagiarism of the other article, since your chapter was written before the other article. Of course, there may be other reasons to edit your thesis chapter before publishing it as (part of) a paper, which is why you should clarify whether or not you are specifically asking about plagiarism (as your tags seem to suggest) or not.

Comment: You have a point, I will edit my question to mention plagiarism specifically

Answer (score 2):

I would add a footnote to your chapter pointing out that "The material here appeared previously in a paper (citation...) that cited this thesis as the source." Or similar wording.

That makes it clear to a reader, which is what you need.

Since this is a thesis, discuss it with your advisor.

Comment: Like you said, ideally the end goal should be to help readers :)